# Removing a class attribute under a div tag + jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var product_features = ['draggable','trackable','colorable'];

 $(document).ready(function () {

 $('div#input .feature draggable').remove();
});
```

```
<h3>Input</h3>
<div id="input">
    <div class="feature draggable">Drag 1</div>
    <div class="feature resizable">Resize</div>
    <div class="feature downloadable">Download</div>
    <div class="feature draggable">Drag 2</div>
    <div class="feature trackable">Track</div>
    <div class="feature colorable">Color</div>
</div>

<h3>Output</h3>
<div id="output"></div>
```

​

Not Able to remove a div class element with feature draggable

```
      $('div#input .feature draggable').remove();
```

Seems something wrong with this part of the code , can any one please point what is wrong in here ?

JS Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/9CzMG/47/

Comment: `draggable` is a class, not a feature!

Comment: I want to remove elements with class name : draggable , how could I do that ?

Comment: How about trying out one of the great answers below ?

Comment: If you want to remove all elements with the class name `draggable`, you would use `$(".draggable").remove();`. If you want to remove all elements with the class names `feature` and `draggable`, you would use `$(".feature.draggable").remove();`. If you want to remove only elements with the class names `feature` and `draggable` that exist inside of a `div` with the id `input`, you would use the answers below.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need,

```
$('div#input .feature.draggable').remove();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('div#input .feature.draggable').remove();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9CzMG/55/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this

```
     $('div#input .draggable').remove();
```